# Where do I go on the Citrix XenApp server to recreate Outlook profile?

Tags: outlook, citrix, xenapp

We are running Citrix Xen Servers 6.5. We are using roaming profiles with folder re-direction.

I am having an issue with a single user's Outlook 2010 application where during the launch process and the inbox loading, the following error will display:

Microsoft Outlook has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.

One cannot continue. I have to click 'close the program' and Outlook closes.

The user has no other problems with any of the other streamed applications. No other users are experiencing any issues with any applications.

It was doing the same in the user's XenApp Desktop environment. No issues via OWA or on the smartphone. No other user has this issue. I resolved the crashing on the XenApp desktop by recreating the local profile there (control panel – mail –profiles).

Where would I go to re-create a new Outlook profile for the user streaming via XenApp? I tried re-creating his Outlook folder under UPM_profile on our file server where all our user data is stored but that doesn't seem to be it.

Path is X:\Shares\XenAppData\XenAppStore\problemsuser\UPM_profile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook.

I tried renaming the folder there but still getting the same error. So where is the ICA client drawing profile information about the user when Outlook is launched?

Comment: First, it's likely not sufficient to clear the Outlook folder under AppData. There will also be settings in registry, which are not easily reset. I would start off by renaming the entire profile, to confirm this is actually related to the profile (which it likely is). Second, did you configure AppData folder redirection?

Comment: Yes, I did configure AppData folder redirection. Renaming the citrix folder did the trick, I thought one could drill down to a more granular fashion for certain streamed applications i.e Outlook but apparently not. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have the following: The folder location where the AppData (Outlook profile info) is stored, the person has Full security permissions to there. If not it can cause crazy problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Adding my comment as answer, so question can be closed or marked answered.*

First, it's likely not sufficient to clear the Outlook folder under AppData. There will also be settings in registry, which are not easily reset.

I would start off by renaming the entire profile, to confirm this is actually related to the profile (which it likely is).

Second, did you configure AppData folder redirection? In that case, you may also want to rename that folder, to avoid that potentially interfering.